# Monitoring programs internet connection

Tags: connection, internet

I'm using Windows XP, without antivirus software. I'm connected to the internet via router. Everytime when I start PC, immediately after, I see that my PC connects with over 20 IPs from diffrent countries,(IPs are externally, not localy LAN) almost connections using same port! I'm not opening any programs myself. I wonder how can I see what programs or threads are trying to open connection, and what port are using, and more useful information.. I already found a software to analyze connections, but it gives me only IP Source, IP Destination, Time, Lenght .. But I need almost to see which program opened this connections, which ports are using.

Comment: Get yourself a software firewall, something like zone alarm. It will provide information on what programs are making outbound connections and will block them unless you explicitly allow it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Miro co's answer.

```
netstat -anb
```

Will provide a list of connections to and from your PC, with remote IP and port information.  The last column will content the PID (processors ID) of the application that made or received the connection.

If you open Task Manager (right click on the task bar) and select `View/Select Columns...` you can enable the PID column.  Now all you need to do is look for the PID for the relevant connections in `netstat` in Task Manager to identify what application is opening the ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command:

```
netstat -n
```

or

```
netstat -b
```

Answer (score 0):

### TCPView

You can use [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) to view the programs that are connecting to the internet, the protocol, local address and port, remote address and port.

[image: TCPView]

### Wireshark

if you need something more advanced you can try [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), it will show you the traffic (Local and remote port, address, protocol, data transmitted,etc...)

[image: Wireshark]

If you need to prevent certain programs from connecting to the internet, you have to install a firewall such as [Comodo firewall](https://personalfirewall.comodo.com/)